Slack Modal Not Opening in Kubernetes, Works Locally
I have a Slack bot running in my Kubernetes Python service, but sometimes the “validating” modal doesn’t open at all. The same bot works perfectly on my local machine.
The code works fine locally, but in Kubernetes, the modal sometimes doesn’t show up, and I don’t get any error logs. What could cause this behavior, and how can I troubleshoot it?
Notes:

The bot runs in a Kubernetes pod using SocketModeHandler.
I’m wondering if there are network or resource constraints in the Kubernetes environment.
Any ideas on why this might be happening?

from slack_bolt import App
from slack_bolt.adapter.socket_mode import SocketModeHandler

class SlackModalHandler:
    def __init__(self):
        self.itcc_number = ''

    def open_modal(self, ack, client, body, command):
        ack()
        view = self.get_view_json('open')
        client.views_open(trigger_id=command["trigger_id"], view=view)

    def validate_and_handle_itcc_submission(self, body, client):
        self.itcc_number = body["view"]["state"]["values"]["itcc_input"]["itcc_text_input"]["value"]
        validating_view = self.get_view_json('validating')

        client.views_open(trigger_id=body["trigger_id"], view=validating_view)
        # Simulate validation logic
        if self.itcc_number == "valid":
            final_view = self.get_view_json('template')
        else:
            final_view = self.get_view_json('error')

        client.views_update(view_id=body["view"]["id"], view=final_view)

    def get_view_json(self, page):
        # Stub method for loading view JSONs
        return {"type": "modal", "title": {"type": "plain_text", "text": page}}

# App initialization
slack_bot_token = 'your-slack-bot-token'
slack_app_token = 'your-slack-app-token'

app = None
try:
    app = App(token=slack_bot_token, name="Deployment Requests Test")
    slackbot_handler = SlackModalHandler()
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Failed to load SlackBot token: {str(e)}")

if app is not None:
    @app.command("/prod_team_test")
    def handle_some_command(ack, client, command, body):
        ack()
        slackbot_handler.open_modal(ack, client, body, command)

    @app.view("message_modal")
    def handle_itcc_submission(ack, client, body):
        ack()
        slackbot_handler.validate_and_handle_itcc_submission(body, client)

# Start the Slack bot using SocketModeHandler
def slackbot_starter():
    try:
        handler = SocketModeHandler(app, app_token=slack_app_token)
        handler.start()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Failed to load Slack App Token: {str(e)}")

slackbot_starter()

I’ve tried the following:

Running the Slack bot locally on my machine, where the modal opens and validates perfectly   every time.
Deployed the exact same code to my Kubernetes service, but sometimes the “validating” modal fails to open. There are no error logs, and everything else in the bot seems to work fine.
I was expecting the modal to always open as it does locally, but in the Kubernetes environment, it fails intermittently. I suspect it might be related to resource constraints or network latency in the Kubernetes pod, but I’m not sure how to confirm this or fix it.
Any insights or troubleshooting suggestions would be helpful!

